# Create UserControl with Different Class Name

Tags: .net, winapi

I'd like to create controls which have a different "class" name.

By class I mean something like this, for example:

Windows toolbar has the class name: Shell_TrayWnd;

Internet Explorer content part has the class name: Internet Explorer_Server;

Generated applications get a class name of something like this: WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d

How can I choose the class name?

Comment: Not possible, Winforms only supports the auto-generated window class name.  CreateParams.ClassName is reserved to create instances of native window classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far as I know, you cannot exert any control over the class name of your user control.